# How to lint deprecated JavaScript methods in Sublime Text?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext, sublimelinter

I use SublimeLinter everyday for linting JavaScript using Sublime Linter. And I don't know is it possible to use it not for syntax check, but for deprecated methods check too.

For example, when I see an object `MyDeprectedObject` or a method `obj.deprecatedMethod` it should show me an error.

I have seen jslint/jshint, eslint and seems like it's not possible to use them for my needs at the moment.

Have you seen a tool I'm looking for? How are you doing deprecated methods/objects check?

Answer (score 0):

ESlint allows you to easily create custom rules. You can create one to check for the names of the objects/properties and display custom errors. You can take a look at any of the existing rules for an example of how to create your own. Here's also a nice tutorial to creating custom rules: https://gist.github.com/jareware/7179093